# Valid JSON to Object in C#

Tags: c#, json, object, literals

I'm trying to deserialize a piece of JSON to a C# object, with little success so far. According to http://jsonlint.com/, the following string is valid JSON. However, there doesn't seem to be any variable names in it. I'm used to seeing JSON that has strings saying "objectID", "objectName" and all that. In this case, I could create a C# object with fields like objectID and objectName and just deserialize the whole thing like this: 
            `Quote deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);`

Any suggestions about how I could do this? I don't see a way it will just deserialize into a series of jagged or nested arrays, for example. Would appreciate any help at all.

```
{
"ABCXYZ": {
    "Wed, Aug 29|Wed|29 Aug 12": [
        [
            "0~W~W4LOW~BND4~~1~X",
            "FR~ 812~ ~~ABC~08/29/2012 06:35~XYZ~08/29/2012 07:45~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-08-29 06:35",
            "2012-08-29 07:45",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "CANX": 2,
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 11.74
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            -1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        [
            "0~W~W4LOW~BND4~~1~X",
            "FR~ 816~ ~~ABC~08/29/2012 14:55~XYZ~08/29/2012 16:05~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-08-29 14:55",
            "2012-08-29 16:05",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "CANX": 2,
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 11.74
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            -1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        [
            "0~W~W4LOW~BND4~~1~X",
            "FR~ 818~ ~~ABC~08/29/2012 19:50~XYZ~08/29/2012 20:55~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-08-29 19:50",
            "2012-08-29 20:55",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "CANX": 2,
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 11.74
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            -1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    ],
    "Thu, Aug 30|Thu|30 Aug 12": [
        [
            "0~W~W4LOW~BND4~~1~X",
            "FR~ 812~ ~~ABC~08/30/2012 06:35~XYZ~08/30/2012 07:45~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-08-30 06:35",
            "2012-08-30 07:45",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "CANX": 2,
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 11.74
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            -1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        [
            "0~W~W4LOW~BND4~~1~X",
            "FR~ 816~ ~~ABC~08/30/2012 08:30~XYZ~08/30/2012 09:40~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-08-30 08:30",
            "2012-08-30 09:40",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "CANX": 2,
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 11.74
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            -1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        [
            "0~W~W4LOW~BND4~~1~X",
            "FR~ 818~ ~~ABC~08/30/2012 22:10~XYZ~08/30/2012 23:15~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-08-30 22:10",
            "2012-08-30 23:15",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "CANX": 2,
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 11.74
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            -1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    ],
    "Fri, Aug 31|Fri|31 Aug 12": [
        [
            "0~W~W4LOW~BND4~~1~X",
            "FR~ 812~ ~~ABC~08/31/2012 06:35~XYZ~08/31/2012 07:45~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-08-31 06:35",
            "2012-08-31 07:45",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "CANX": 2,
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 11.74
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            -1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        [
            "0~C~C4LOW~BND4~~1~X",
            "FR~ 816~ ~~ABC~08/31/2012 13:20~XYZ~08/31/2012 14:30~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-08-31 13:20",
            "2012-08-31 14:30",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "CANX": 2,
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 32.74
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            2,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        [
            "0~C~C4LOW~BND4~~1~X",
            "FR~ 818~ ~~ABC~08/31/2012 19:50~XYZ~08/31/2012 20:55~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-08-31 19:50",
            "2012-08-31 20:55",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "CANX": 2,
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 32.74
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            3,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    ],
    "Sat, Sep 01|Sat|01 Sep 12": [
        [
            "0~C~C4LOW~BND4~~1~X",
            "FR~ 812~ ~~ABC~09/01/2012 08:05~XYZ~09/01/2012 09:15~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-09-01 08:05",
            "2012-09-01 09:15",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "CANX": 2,
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 32.74
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            -1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        [
            "0~W~W4LOW~BND4~~1~X",
            "FR~ 818~ ~~ABC~09/01/2012 17:00~XYZ~09/01/2012 18:05~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-09-01 17:00",
            "2012-09-01 18:05",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "CANX": 2,
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 11.74
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            2,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    ],
    "Sun, Sep 02|Sun|02 Sep 12": [
        [
            "0~N~N16SEP~FCCG~~3~X",
            "FR~ 812~ ~~ABC~09/02/2012 06:35~XYZ~09/02/2012 07:45~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-09-02 06:35",
            "2012-09-02 07:45",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 9.75
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            -1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        [
            "0~H~H4LOW~BND4~~1~X",
            "FR~ 816~ ~~ABC~09/02/2012 14:55~XYZ~09/02/2012 16:05~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-09-02 14:55",
            "2012-09-02 16:05",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "CANX": 2,
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 23.74
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        [
            "0~K~K4LOW~BND4~~1~X",
            "FR~ 818~ ~~ABC~09/02/2012 20:25~XYZ~09/02/2012 21:30~",
            "Regular Fare",
            "2012-09-02 20:25",
            "2012-09-02 21:30",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "CANX": 2,
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "Tax": 36,
                            "FarePrice": 33.99
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            -1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    ],
    "Mon, Sep 03|Mon|03 Sep 12": [
        [
            "0~N~N16SEP~FCCG~~3~X",
            "FR~ 812~ ~~ABC~09/03/2012 06:35~XYZ~09/03/2012 07:45~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-09-03 06:35",
            "2012-09-03 07:45",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 9.75
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            -1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        [
            "0~A~A4LOW~BND4~~1~X",
            "FR~ 818~ ~~ABC~09/03/2012 14:35~XYZ~09/03/2012 15:40~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-09-03 14:35",
            "2012-09-03 15:40",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "CANX": 2,
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 17.74
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            -1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        [
            "0~N~N16SEP~FCCG~~3~X",
            "FR~ 816~ ~~ABC~09/03/2012 22:55~XYZ~09/03/2012 23:59~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-09-03 22:55",
            "2012-09-03 23:59",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 9.75
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            3,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    ],
    "Tue, Sep 04|Tue|04 Sep 12": [
        [
            "0~N~N16SEP~FCCG~~3~X",
            "FR~ 812~ ~~ABC~09/04/2012 06:35~XYZ~09/04/2012 07:45~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-09-04 06:35",
            "2012-09-04 07:45",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 9.75
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            -1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        [
            "0~N~N16SEP~FCCG~~3~X",
            "FR~ 818~ ~~ABC~09/04/2012 19:50~XYZ~09/04/2012 20:55~",
            "No Taxes",
            "2012-09-04 19:50",
            "2012-09-04 20:55",
            [
                {
                    "ADT": [
                        1,
                        "0.00",
                        "0",
                        {
                            "WC": 6,
                            "ETS": 0.25,
                            "FarePrice": 9.75
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            -1,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Are you interested in all values contained in this JSON or only some of them? What do you intend to do with this data once deserialized?

Comment: As far as I can see, that could only be de-serialized to nested arrays.  You would then have to use some kind of lookup of array positions to read this into an object.

Comment: What is generating this json ? it's a ajax post of your own application ? it's external ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

foreach (JProperty item in obj["ABCXYZ"].Children())
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    foreach (var x in item)
    {
        foreach (var y in x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t==> " + y[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

*PS: your json is hard to read. [Json Viewer](http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/) can help to see the structure of it easily.*

Comment: @TarbhJohnnyDick `obj.First.First`

Answer (score 0):

Newtonsoft is my favorite way of doing anything JSON in C#, and I regularly work with JSON in different programming languages, using it is as simple as using Javascript or PHP.

Here's one of the simplest examples

```
string json_string = @"{
                  Firstname: ""Jane"",
                  Lastname: ""Doe"",
                  Age: 36,
                  IsEmployed: true,
                  IsMarried: true,
                  Children: 4
              }";
              
var person = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json_string);

Console.WriteLine(person.Forename);
Console.WriteLine(person.Lastname);
Console.WriteLine(person.Age);
Console.WriteLine(person.IsEmployed);
Console.WriteLine(person.IsMarried);
Console.WriteLine(person.Children);
```

It generates objects on the fly, no matter the structure! Other solutions don't work in all .NET versions.

I wrote a simple, easy-to-follow article here https://turmanauli.medium.com/a-complete-guide-for-serializing-json-to-dynamic-objects-on-the-fly-in-c-7ab4799f648d
about how to install and use Newtonsoft via NuGet Package Manager in your Visual Studio project.